# Why am I not getting any state value in the first render after setState?

Tags: reactjs, rendering, use-effect, use-state, react-leaflet

I am using the co-ordinates from the workout object to get the `cityName` of the workout. I am not getting the `cityName` for the first workout object. Then the `cityName` gets passed on to the second workout object. I got the co-ordinates from clickEvent on the map container.

I get the coords by clicking on the map and getting the latlng from mapevent. By clicking the map the input container gets displayed. These are the workouts array of objects which i get from input values after submitting the form.

here is the link to the project: [react-mapty](https://react-mapty.netlify.app)
you just need to click anywhere in the map to display the workout form.

```
const workouts = [
{
id: 1,
coords: {latitude: 56.27360151291927, 
longitude:-82.84886256490017},
},

{
id: 2,
coords: {latitude: 49.27360151291927, 
longitude: -75.84886256490017},
}
]
```

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const RenderLocation = () => {
  const [workouts, setWorkouts] = useState([]);
  const [cityName, setCityName] = useState('');

  if (workoutType === 'running') {
    const runningData = {
      id,
      coords,
      workoutType,
      distance,
      duration,
      cadence,
      pace,
      cityName,
    };

    setWorkouts((result) => [...result, runningData]);
    clearInputs();
  } else if (workoutType === 'cycling') {
    const cyclingData = {
      id,
      coords,
      workoutType,
      distance,
      duration,
      elevation,
      speed,
      cityName,
    };

    setWorkouts((result) => [...result, cyclingData]);
    clearInputs();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    workouts.map((exercise) => {
      fetch(
        `https://geocode.xyz/${exercise.coords.latitude},${exercise.coords.longitude}?geoit=json`
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result);
          setCityName(`${result.staddress}, ${result.city}`);
        });
    });
  }, [workouts]);

  return (
    <>

     workouts.map((workout) =>{
      
      return(
          <h2 key={workout.id} className="workout-title">
          {${workout.cityName}`}
          </h2>
      )})

    </>
    )
};

export default RenderLocation;
```

This is how the result looks:
[image]

Comment: Your `useState` seems to be outside of your component code... is that a copy paste issue?

Comment: yeah that was a copy and paste issue

Comment: Can you fix it please via the edit function?!

Comment: i tried so many ways to render specific cityname. I created array of city name and tried rendering. It would display all the cityname for each workout object.

Comment: I can help you with this I just need to see the actual code and as you have it right now in your question I can't engage with as it's broken. Just edit your question and move the `useState` into your component and I'll have a look

Comment: all of my souce codes are here: https://github.com/kashcodernyc/react-mapty/tree/master/src

Comment: The entire `if (workoutType === 'running') {` block is a side effect and should be inside a `useEffect`

Comment: And your actual `useEffect` loop will override each `cityName` with every iteration. I don't understand what you're trying to do here. `cityName` can have only one value since it is a string but you're iterating an array and setting it each time.

Comment: i am using useffect so that it doesn't create an infinite loop. I am mapping through the workouts array to get the co-ordinates of each workout. That way i can use that co-ordinates to get the location name.

Comment: the codes i have provided is just a small part of the project. i have the all the src folder in the github links i have provided. The main issue is that every time i setCityName(result) it doesn't render first time but the result goes to the second render.

Comment: i edited the code. May be this can give you a better idea at that i am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Dominik also added the link to the project.